# How to pass parameter and json both in http request request body in jmeter?

Tags: json, jmeter

I need to pass those parameters and JSON in a request body of HTTP request in Jmeter.

```
 UserId=47&Token=c41240ca195c47b7821465d328d5af16&ClientId=1&meeting={
    "InternetConnectionType":"WIFI",
    "DeviceID":"3d6f9c346da00a32",
    "NetworkCarrierName":"VODAFONEIN",
    "BatteryValue":"22",
    "AppVersion":"1.1.3",
    "OSVersion":"4.4.2",
    "InLongitude":"77.0384036",
    "Remarks":"hii hcl",
    "LastPhoneRestart":"Wed Jun 15 14:32:14 GMT+05:30 2016",
    "OutDateTime":"20-06-2016 11:54:09",
    "OutLongitude":"77.0384036",
    "IsApproved":"0",
    "SimNo":"",
    "OutLatitude":"28.4181932",
    "AttendanceType":"G",
    "InDateTime":"20-06-2016 11:54:08",
    "GeofenceAssignedId":"10114",
    "LastWifiNetworkName":"YomaTech",
    "InLatitude":"28.4181932",
    "IMEINo":"359453066495811",
    "DeviceDateTime":"20-06-2016 11:54:08",
    "GeofenceId":"1"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

[image: HTTP Request]

Out of interest and just in case it helps to avoid similar questions in the future: why don't you just record your test scenario with [JMeter's Proxy Server](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension)?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried below solution in JMeter 4, and it worked for me.
Follow below steps:

1) Add "HTTP Header Manager"

2) Add required headers and parameters in key-value format

3) Add "HTTP Request

4) Provide server name, port, method=POST and path

5) Select Body Data tab

6) Enter json body

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I tried solve similar problem in current version of Apache JMeter 5.1.

- I set up JSON body for HTTP Request element (bookmark Body Data).
- Added parameter into HTTP Default element (bookmark Parameters).

In this case parameter were added after JSON body and test fails for bad JSON format.

My solution was added parameter into path in HTTP request. But default behavior seems little buggy for me.