# How to pass both parameter and JSON in one single HTTP request body with having JSON a variable [JMeter]

Tags: json, variables, jmeter, httprequest

I have a similar but extended question for the below question.
[How to pass parameter and json both in http request request body in jmeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39284911/how-to-pass-parameter-and-json-both-in-http-request-request-body-in-jmeter/75004992)?

I will take the same example as mentioned in the above question/link.
Have to pass multiple parameters,

```
UserId=47
meeting={
    "DeviceID":${deviceID},
    "NetworkCarrierName":"VODAFONEIN",
    "BatteryValue":"22",
    "AppVersion":"1.1.3",
 }
```

As you can see, DeviceID have a value from variable deviceID. I want to pass all these parameters and JSON in one single http request body.
What would be the approach for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In parameter I have to add the variable for value part for whichever key I want to refer to. It will work fine.
[This image shows that..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qy76v.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The same approach will work fine, you can use JMeter Variables anywhere in your test plan, if there is a [User Defined Variable](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables) or a [pre-defined variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars) or a variable coming from a [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) - JMeter will substitute the variable placeholder with its respective value in the runtime:

[image]

If you're uncertain regarding how to properly build your request the easiest is just recording it using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)